# Boost::geometry::intersection gives wrong output. version BOOST_1_57_0

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, boost-geometry

This might be a question asked multiple times. But I cross checked similar questions, to make sure mine is not repeated.

I have a source code that uses `boost::geometry::intersection` in the code, to get the resultant of intersection between two polygons. I have `boost::geometry::correct` tested for the polygons used. The sequence of points in the polygon is clockwise. Everything seems right, but I get incorrect output from the `boost::geometry::intersection` call.

Please help me identify what the issue here is.

This is class Point definition:

```
class Point {
public:
    double _x, _y;
    Point();
    Point(double, double);
    Point(const Point& orig);
    void SetX(double x);
    void SetY(double y);
    double GetX() const;
    double GetY() const;
};
```

code where boost libraries are used

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Point, double, cs::cartesian, _x, _y)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_RING(std::vector<Point>)

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bd2 = boost::geometry::model::d2;

std::vector<Point> ORCAModel :: BoostPolyIntersect( std::vector<Point>& poly_1,
                                                    std::vector<Point>& poly_2,
                                                    bool &intersect_FLAG) const{

    std::vector<Point> poly_result;

    bg::correct(poly_1);
    bg::correct(poly_2);

    bg::intersection(poly_1, poly_2, poly_result);
    intersect_FLAG = (int(poly_result.size()) > 2)
    return poly_result;

    }
```

I used basic iostream to check the output. (Note : The input values are taken from one of the run sequences of the program, but not fed in as a user input)

```
--------------poly_1------------
( 0.075 : 27.2 )  ----  ( 27 : 27.2 )  ----  ( 27 : -22.8 )  ----  ( 0.075 : -22.8 )  ----  ( 0.075 : 27.2 )  ----  
--------------poly_2------------
( -23 : -22.8 )  ----  ( -23 : 3.925 )  ----  ( 27 : 3.925 )  ----  ( 27 : -22.8 )  ----  ( -23 : -22.8 )  ----  
result in bstpolyint size : 3
-----------------RESULT  POLY ------------------------
( 27 : 3.925 )  ----  ( 27 : -22.8 )  ----  ( 0.0750023 : 3.925 )  ----
```

The output should have 4 points and is clearly missing a point `(0.07500 : - 22.8)` .

> (Note : The input points are rounded off during the display check. Not manually though.
>   When the displayed points were used in the test case, the results were
>   correct. But it is clearly because of the round off, the points used
>   in the original program for calculation and in the test case are
>   perturbed.)

Please help to identify the issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

EDIT : This is my test case. The commented lines polygon_1 & polygon_2 are rounded off values. Using those values gives 4 corners of the new polygon. The magnified values in use result in only 3 corners as got in the release mode.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE convexHull
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "../../geometry/Point.h"

#include <vector> 
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <string>

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Point, double, cs::cartesian, _x, _y)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_RING(std::vector<Point>)

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bd2 = boost::geometry::model::d2;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(convexHull)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(poly_Intersect_Test) {

//   std::vector<Point> polygon_1 = {Point(0.075, 27.2), Point( 27,  27.2), Point( 27, -22.8 ), Point( 0.075, -22.8 ), Point( 0.075,  27.2 )};
//   std::vector<Point> polygon_2 = {Point( -23, -22.8 ), Point( -23, 3.925 ), Point( 27, 3.925 ), Point( 27, -22.8 ), Point ( -23, -22.8 )};


  std::vector<Point> polygon_1 = {Point(749, 271999), Point(270000, 272000), Point(270000, -228000), Point(750, -227999), Point(749, 271999)};
  std::vector<Point> polygon_2 = {Point(-230000, -228000), Point (-230000, 39250) , Point(270000, 39250), Point (270000, -228000), Point (-230000, -228000)};
  std::vector<Point> polygon_result;

  bg::intersection(polygon_1, polygon_2, polygon_result);
  std::string points = "";
  for (auto it : polygon_result)
    points = points + "---" + it.toString();
  BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(false, points);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: Can you post a drawing? It is not easy to visualize the geometry from coordinates.

Comment: If you tag your question [tag:boost-geometry], it'll have a better chance to be found by an expert in the library. And a more complete (preferably simplified) example would also help.

Comment: It's not clear where the problem happens. Can you print actual input for bg::intersection with maximum precision?

Comment: I dont understand either why this happens. The actual input comes from the halfplane intersection computation. Do you think it might be an issue with the stl used?

Comment: @cv_and_he  & n.m  : added my test case too. ty fr your time

Comment: I have never used this library seriously, but if I understand [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html) correctly you need to pass a vector of polygons/rings as "GeometryOut" in the call to `intersection` (It says a "collection" of geometries, you were passing a collection of points and that behaves differently apparently). [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00c53d8df01771e8) seems to work. Hopefully someone will be able to give an answer without "seems" and "apparently".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not intersecting polygons, you're passing *rings*. Now, the problem is that you don't pass the right concept as an output collection.

Quite simply, two arbitrary polygons (evens rings) might have multiple disjunct intersection polygons. You need to accomodate multiple intersections in the output type. @cv_and_he's further simplified and extended:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df38732976c5c1df)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector> 
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <string>

class Point {
public:
    double _x, _y;
    Point():_x(),_y(){}
    Point(double x, double y):_x(x),_y(y){}
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Point, double, cs::cartesian, _x, _y)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_RING(std::vector<Point>)

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

template <typename G>
void test(G const& g1, G const& g2) {
    std::cout << "----\nIntersecting\n\t" << bg::wkt(g1) << "\n\t" << bg::wkt(g2) << "\nresult: ";

    std::vector<G> polygon_results;
    bg::intersection<G, G>(g1, g2, polygon_results);

    for (auto polygon : polygon_results)
        std::cout << bg::wkt(polygon) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    using Ring = std::vector<Point>;

    test<Ring>(
            {{749,  271999},  {270000, 272000}, {270000, -228000},    {750, -227999},     {749,  271999}},
            {{-230000, -228000}, {-230000,  39250}, {270000,   39250}, {270000, -228000}, {-230000, -228000}});
    test<Ring>(
            {{0.075,   27.2},  { 27,   27.2}, { 27, -22.8 }, { 0.075, -22.8 }, { 0.075,  27.2 }},
            {{ -23, -22.8 }, { -23, 3.925 }, { 27, 3.925 },    { 27, -22.8 },   { -23, -22.8 }});
}
```

Output:

```
----
Intersecting
    POLYGON((749 271999,270000 272000,270000 -228000,750 -227999,749 271999))
    POLYGON((-230000 -228000,-230000 39250,270000 39250,270000 -228000,-230000 -228000))
result: POLYGON((270000 39250,270000 -228000,750 -227999,749.465 39250,270000 39250))
----
Intersecting
    POLYGON((0.075 27.2,27 27.2,27 -22.8,0.075 -22.8,0.075 27.2))
    POLYGON((-23 -22.8,-23 3.925,27 3.925,27 -22.8,-23 -22.8))
result: POLYGON((27 3.925,27 -22.8,0.075 -22.8,0.075 3.925,27 3.925))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cv_and_he and sehe .. now it works fine. Didn't realize that I have to provide a multi-ring as the output collector.